# MS Access - VBA Do while TxtBox is Not Empty

Tags: sql, vba, database-connection, do-while, is-empty

```
Public Sub Ohno()
Dim stsql As String, results As String
Dim rs As Object, Db As Object, con As Object
Dim num As Integer
Dim start As Object

Set Db = CurrentDb()
Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

num = 1
For num = 1 To 2
  Do While IsEmpty(Forms("setup").Controls("TxtBoxEntry" & num)) = False
    Set start = Forms("setup").Controls("TxtBoxEntry" & num)
    stsql = "SELECT [Crosswalk].[Oracle GL Acct] FROM Crosswalk WHERE [Crosswalk].[Legacy GL Acct]= '" & start & "' "
    rs.Open stsql, con
    results = rs(0).Value
    Forms("setup").Controls("TxtBoxRslt" & num).Value = results
  Loop
Next

Set con = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

I keep getting: [Operation isn't allow while Object is Open - click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNh98.png)
the code does work for the first txtbox and stops to give me the above error.  Am I setting up myself for failure on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the recordset after using it.  Try adding `rs.Close`:

```
Set start = Forms("setup").Controls("TxtBoxEntry" & num)
stsql = "SELECT [Crosswalk].[Oracle GL Acct] 
         FROM Crosswalk WHERE [Crosswalk].[Legacy GL Acct]= '" & start & "' "
rs.Open stsql, con
results = rs(0).Value
Forms("setup").Controls("TxtBoxRslt" & num).Value = results
rs.Close   -- Add this here
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thank you so very much. I get soo stuck that I feel like an idiot.